# Google is indexing my target-tab URL with ID'S

Tags: html, url, seo, robots.txt

Need your help here.

I have a page - https://www.iservis.info/ 
-> In Navigation you have iPhone, iPad, Macbook, Macs, Watches which lead to certain tabs in this page -> https://iservis.info/opravy/

So I have url for MacBook -> https://iservis.info/opravy/?tab=target-tab-macbook which open certain tab.

PROBLEM IS - GOOGLE INDEXING THESE URLS :///

What exactly I should type to robots.txt or even to sitemap?

Thanks a lot for help

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 0):

In the old version of search console in Crawl > URL parameters you can configure what do all parameters that you have in the website.

You need specify this parameters don't affects to the content of the page to solve this problem.